# Restrict the area of a raster data with a shapefile

Tags: python, raster, shapefile

I am using Python GIS. I have a raster data ('driver': 'GTiff') for the entire world. I also have a shapefile for African continent

I would like to restrict the area of the raster data just to the African continent using the shapefile. For that, I am using module mask of rasterio.

I am using the following code:

```
from rasterio.mask import mask

transform = mask(raster_data, shapes = africa.geometry, crop = true, nodata=np.nan)
```

It gives the following error: *Cannot convert fill_value nan to dtype uint8.*

Any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `gdal` set of tools?

Comment: No, I am a bit new using python and gis data.

Comment: OK, take a look at those and you should find an answer

Comment: I took a look to gdal tools but I do not find the answer to my question.

Comment: My mistake-- I think I see it now. You have `nodata=np.nan`, but I'm guessing the NODATA value of `raster_data` isn't actually `NaN`. It's probably `-32768` or something, but you can use `gdalinfo` to check for sure.